# Problema con getters y setters en 2 metodos

Tags: java, get, set

Soy nuevo en esto de java y en lo de getters y setters y estaba intentando hacer este codigo de pedir la fecha y hora actual usando dos metodos pero cuando se ingresa todo en el set de todos los atributos en un metodo, cuando quiero usar otro metodo para poner el get de esos mismos atributos, solo me sale que no hay nada ahi y me sale 0 a pesar de haber puesto valores antes

```
    public void establecer() {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        Tiempo tiempo1 = new Tiempo();
        Fecha fecha1 = new Fecha();
        int dia;
        int mes;
        int año;
        int hora;
        int minuto; 
        int segundo;
        //fecha
        do {
            System.out.println("Por favor ingrese el dia actual: ");
            dia=entrada.nextInt();
            if(dia>31) {
                System.out.println("Dia invalido, recuerde poner el numero del"
                        + " dia, por favor ingrese de nuevo");
            }
        }while(dia>31);
        fecha1.setDia(dia);
        do {
            System.out.println("Por favor ingrese el mes actual: ");
            mes=entrada.nextInt();
            if(mes>12) {
                System.out.println("Mes invalido, recuerde poner el numero del mes en vez del"
                        + " nombre, por favor intente de nuevo");
            }
        }while (mes>12);
        fecha1.setMes(mes);
        do {
            System.out.println("Por favor ingrese el año actual: ");
            año=entrada.nextInt();
            if(año<1940||año>2022) {
                System.out.println("Año invalido por favor intente de nuevo");
            }
        }while (año<1940||año>2022);
        fecha1.setAño(año);
        //hora
        do {
            System.out.println("Ingrese la hora actual en formato de 24 horas: ");
            hora=entrada.nextInt();
            if(hora>23) {
                System.out.println("Hora invalida, recuerde usar el formato de 24 horas,"
                        + " intente de nuevo");
            }
        }while (hora>23);
        tiempo1.setHora(hora);
        do {
            System.out.println("Ingrese el minuto actual: ");
            minuto=entrada.nextInt();
            if(minuto>60) {
                System.out.println("Minuto invalido intente de nuevo");
            }
        }while(minuto>60);
        tiempo1.setMinuto(minuto);
        do {
            System.out.println("Ingrese el segundo actual: ");
            segundo=entrada.nextInt();
            if(segundo>60) {
                System.out.println("Segundo invalido intente de nuevo");
            }
        }while(segundo>60);
        tiempo1.setSegundo(segundo);
    }
```

pero cuando intento obtener el get en este metodo, solo no me sale nada

```
    public void imprimir() {
        Tiempo tiempo1 = new Tiempo();
        Fecha fecha1 = new Fecha();
        System.out.println("La fecha actual con su hora es:");
        System.out.println(fecha1.getDia()+"/"+fecha1.getMes()+"/"+fecha1.getAño());
        System.out.println(tiempo1.getHora()+":"+tiempo1.getMinuto()+":"+tiempo1.getSegundo());
    }
```

como puedo hacer que en este otro metodo llamado imprimir me de todos los datos que ya ha ingresado el usuario?
y perdon de nuevo si es que esto es algo obvio de resolver pero soy algo nuevo en java

Comment: en tu método `establecer` estas creando un objeto de la clase tiempo y otro de la clase fecha aunque ambos se llamen igual a los objetos de tu clase imprimir no significa que sean igual ,son  otros objetos creados en otro método con el mismo nombre entonces..seria mejor que crees tiempo1 y fecha1 fuera de los métodos y los pases como parametro en tus metodos `void establecer(Tiempo tiempo1,Fecha fecha1)`//`void imprimir(Tiempo tiempo1,Fecha fecha1)`

Answer (score 0):

Define la instancia de la clase `Tiempo` y `Fecha` solo en una ocasión ya que el problema por el cual no tienes valores es que creas una vez la instancia cuando guardas los valores y nuevamente cuando los tratas de obtener.

Para evitar el problema define dos variables y dentro del método establecer() solo inicializa las clases:

```
  Tiempo tiempo1 = null;
  Fecha fecha1 = null;

  public void establecer() {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        tiempo1 = new Tiempo(); //*Inicializa clase
        fecha1 = new Fecha();  //*Inicializa clase
     ...
     ...
     ...
    }
```

En tu método `imprimir()` no inicialices ya que existe `fecha1` y `tiempo1`, vas a poder obtener sus valores:

```
public void imprimir() {
        //Tiempo tiempo1 = new Tiempo();
        //Fecha fecha1 = new Fecha();
        System.out.println("La fecha actual con su hora es:");
        System.out.println(fecha1.getDia()+"/"+fecha1.getMes()+"/"+fecha1.getAño());
        System.out.println(tiempo1.getHora()+":"+tiempo1.getMinuto()+":"+tiempo1.getSegundo());
    }
```